# How to create customizable collects in Autopilot(Twilio)?

Tags: twilio, twilio-autopilot

I would like to know how o create a customizable Collect for a task in Autopilot. i.e if I want to add new questions to the Collect, all I would be needing is to change the collect from the backend of my application. Is there any method for doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the REST API to [update the actions for a task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/task?code-sample=code-update-a-task-to-set-task-actions&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x%5D).

Or, if you set an actions URL for the task to point to your own application, then you can handle the questions in your application. That way you could build an interface that allows you to create Collect questions in your application and when Twilio Autopilot makes a webhook request to the actions URL for the task, your application can return the [Actions JSON](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions) containing the up to date Collect questions.

Comment: Thank you, this one is a real-life saver.